# how to check why NSXMLParser initWithContentsOfURL method is taking too long?

Tags: ios

I send an update to my server every 5 seconds with a timer. In response I receive an XML from the server which I parse using `NSXMLParser`. MyParser is set as the delegate and implements the needed callbacks to parse the document (including `- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError`).
most of the time the parsing is successful but every few minutes `initWithContentsOfURL` gets stuck for about a minute (almost exactly one minute avery time), then `[parser parse]` returns false and after that i keep getting successful parsing till the next failure.

```
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5
                                                  target:self
                                                selector:@selector(parseDocument)
                                                userInfo:nil
                                                 repeats:YES];

- (void) parseDocument {
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        NSLog(@"before NSXMLParser alloc");
        NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"https://secure.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dbm?xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"]];
        NSLog(@"after NSXMLParser alloc");

        MyParser *myParser = [[MyParser alloc] initParser:4];
        [parser setDelegate:myParser];
        BOOL result = [parser parse];
        if (result) {
            NSLog(@"Successful parse");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Failed parse");
        }
    });
}
```

My question is how can I check why the parse (which fails) is taking about a minute and than returns false???

parseErrorOccurred is never called.

I checked the server side and everything is working and running as it should.

Any ideas????

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**

As it turns out, `[parser parse]` is working fine, the problem occurs in `initWithContentsOfURL` , every few minutes this line takes one minute (instead of 1-2 second) than the parse returns false.

i checked server side if everything is ok within that minute and it looks fine.
also checked if parser is not nil, which it isn't.

any suggestions on how to check whats causing the problem every few minutes in this line: `NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"https://secure.xxxxxxx.dbm?xxxxxxxxxx"]];`, will be very appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Check whether parser is not nil and your xml is correctly formatted

Comment: added a check to see if parser is not nil before [parser parse] and checked the xml again. XML is properly formatted and parser is not nil , however still same thing happens. Thanks for the help

Comment: i'd propose modifying the question given it has nothing to do with the parser

Comment: you're right, edited the question a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switch to an asynchronous fetch that explicitly alerts you upon a communications error: `NSURLSession` if under 7 or later, the appropriate class method of `NSURLConnection` if support for 6 is required. Either way you'll end up with an `NSError`, an `NSData` and an `NSURLResponse`, which you can cast to `NSHTTPURLResponse` to check for a 200 response code.

If there's no error, a valid response code and greater-than-zero length data, proceed to hand the data to an `NSXMLParser`.

EDIT: so, I'm on a real computer now (rather than an iPad) and therefore can add that I'd gravitate towards code like:

```
[[[NSURLSession sharedSession]
    dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://secure.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.dbm?xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"]
    completionHandler:
    ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
    {
        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;

        if(httpResponse.statusCode != 200 || error || ![data length])
        {
            NSLog(@"Some error condition");
            return;
        }

        NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
        [parser setDelegate:myParser];
        BOOL result = [parser parse];
        if (result) {
            NSLog(@"Successful parse");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Failed parse");
        }
    }] resume];
```

I've favoured `NSURLSession` even though I'm just then telling the returned task to `resume` and never using any of the improved functionality over `NSURLConnection`'s asynchronous mechanism, such as cancellation, because it is anecdotally much better at caching and because it'll automatically ensure an appropriate place is found to accumulate results and ultimately dispatch the completion handler asynchronously. So that's a few lines saved.

Comment: Thanks i'll try that and see what turns up

Comment: I still haven't got it working exactly as i hoped (still working on it) but it seems your answer set me on the right path so i will mark it as correct.
Thanks

Comment: Sorry for having been vague initially; I was typing on an iPad. You've probably arrived at the same general structure as I suggest but nevertheless, the code now added is roughly what I would expect to arrive at. Probably with something more robust for error handling than just logging a catch-all comment...